# Worklight 6.2 access disabled French Android issue

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobile-application, worklight-server

I'm trying to remote disable the application on my android platform. I provided the EN message with the URL and uploaded the csv file for FR.

CSV content:

```
fr,Une nouvelle version de l’application mobile de SRC de company est maintenant à votre disposition. La taille du fichier est de 8 Mo. Veuillez effectuer la mise à jour dès maintenant pour pouvoir continuer à utiliser l’application
```

However, when I launch my device which is in FR, I'm still getting the EN message.

I'm not sure what is the issue as I know this is a WL console functionality to detect the device language.

Remote disable code:

```
   function getLanguage() {
    return (WL.App.getDeviceLanguage() || 'en');
}
var downloadNewVersionBtn="Download New Version";
var updateMessageTitle = "Update Is Available";

 if  (getLanguage() == "fr") {
    downloadNewVersionBtn = "Télécharger la nouvelle version";
    updateMessageTitle = "Nouvelle version prête à télécharger";

}
onErrorRemoteDisableDenial : function (message, downloadLink) {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                    updateMessageTitle,
                    message,
                    [
                     {text: downloadNewVersionBtn , handler: function() {WL.App.openURL(downloadLink, "_blank");}}]
            );
        },
```

Am I missing something?

The exact same code works for iPhone.

WL Server version: 6.2.0.01.20141013-1735

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of previous defects related to remote disable notifications in multiple languages, that can result in the device displaying a remote disable notification based on the locale of the **server** rather than the **client**.  There's one I know is specifically applicable to 6.2, but I don't immediately know if it was fixed in 6.2 (I know it was fixed for 6.3 and later) - and if it was, I'm not sure that fix would be in the build you're running, since it's more than a year and a half old....

A quick test you might be able to use to see if you are affected by one of these issues is to change the locale of the server to fr_FR.  If you're affected, you should see the disable message on devices appearing in French - even if the locale of the device is set to an English locale.

If you are affected, the very first thing I would suggest would be to apply the latest 6.2 iFix and determine if this resolves the issue.  If it does not, please open a PMR and the support team will help determine if this is indeed a problem that was fixed in 6.3 but wasn't backported to 6.2, and will see if we can get that fix backported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the weird thing is that I have another app running on the same console and it is working for Android, not sure how two apps using the exact same direct update code behave differently.

Comment: We tested the same app on MFP console, and the issue disappeared. Looks an issue on WL 6.2